# Why is Golang Intellisense slow in VS Code when changing imports?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have the `ms-vscode.go` Go extension installed in my VS Code setup and am using the `gopls` language server.  The language server seems to perform well with Intellisense operations except when I am editing imports, at which point there is considerable lag as every edit to the import takes several seconds to update.

For example, the following is a replay of typing in manually `import "net/http"` letter-by-letter (rather than copy/paste).  The clip runs at 20x speed, so it takes about 1.8 minutes from when I stop typing the import statement to when the language server gets to the correct error of `"net/http" imported but not used`:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

My go-related settings:

```
  "go.useLanguageServer": true,
  "go.alternateTools": {
      "go-langserver": "gopls"
  },
```

Output from `gopls` reveals that much time is spent in `go list`:

```
4.037297s for ...go "list" "-e" "-json" "-compiled=true" "-test=true" "-export=false" "-deps=true" "-find=false" "--" ...
```

for every change.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34360 may be related

Comment: Your animation matches the behavior I've been seeing with v0.1.2, and I believe it's followed me for a few versions (it mostly doesn't affect me). Can confirm stamblerre's comment though: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34360#issuecomment-532909209 upgrading to `v0.1.7` resolved the long delay on save (with import). Now I only get a 1-2s slowdown on save (removing import), hopefully that works for you too!

Comment: I am on `v0.1.7` :(

Comment: Filed https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34414

Comment: The next gopls 0.3.0 (https://github.com/golang/go/milestone/129) should help. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 4):

That might be because:

- [`go tools`](https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/cmd/gopls) does <del>not yet</del> support autocompletion of unimported packages #31906: [issue 31906](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31906): resolved in Jan. 2020.
- [`saibing/tools`](https://github.com/saibing/tools) does.

Before Jan. 2020 and gopls 0.3.0, You could try and see if the issue persist with `saibing/tools`, using Go 1.13 in module mode.

```
git clone https://github.com/saibing/tools
cd tools/gopls
go install
```

Make sure your `~/go/bin` (using the default `GOPATH`) does show a new `gopls` executable with a recent timestamp.

Relaunch VSCode then.

Note: [`microsoft/vscode-go` issue 2484](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2484) ("Go: Autocomplete Unimported Packages" feature when using Go modules") just got resolved (Jan. 2020) too:

> Enabling the setting `go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages` used to provide completions for unimported packages.
>   When such a completion item was selected by the user, not only was the current word completed, but an import statement is added in the file for that package.

This now works with Go modules.

Again, gopls 0.3.0 should help.

---

My gopls settings:

```
"gopls": {
    "usePlaceholders": true, // add parameter placeholders when completing a function
    "enhancedHover": true, // experimental to improve quality of hover (will be on by default soon)
},
```

But also:

```
"[go]": {
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "none",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true
    },
},
"go.lintTool": "golangci-lint",
"go.useLanguageServer": true,
"go.languageServerExperimentalFeatures": {
    "format": true,
    "autoComplete": true
},
```

Comment: I built and installed saibing/tools, and verified that autocomplete of un-imported packages works, but editing imports still requires several seconds per edit for the server to catch up.

Comment: @tbhartman Can you edit your question, adding your gopls-related user settings?

Comment: @tbhartman I have edited the answer with my settings. Maybe one of them would have a beneficial side effect?